# Which method or action hook is fired when changing shipping method on checkout page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to change the address fields to be 'required', when the user will select shipping method that is other than "local pickup".

I managed make it optional by default (local pickup is selected by default) using a filter, like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'disable_required_address_shipping' );

function disable_required_address_shipping($fields ) {
    if ( check_if_local_pickup() ) {

        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = false;
    }

    return $fields;

}

function check_if_local_pickup() {
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; 
    if ($chosen_shipping == 'local_pickup') { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I need to change it dynamically using an action.

I tried to look for a solution here and couldn't find one.

Is there any action that fires when changing shipping method? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fire an action when shipping method is changed you may use `do_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen', $chosen_method );`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen', 'check_if_local_pickup', 10, 1 );
function check_if_local_pickup( $chosen_method ) {
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; 
    if ($chosen_shipping == 'local_pickup') { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

References: 
[woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen (hookr.io)](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen/)
[Source code: class WC_Shipping (line 311)](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shipping.html#311)

Comment: This is old, but should it not be "add_action"?

Comment: @TASan Yes you are completely right, thanks.